# How to open browser at a preferred location and size with Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(...)) in Java?

Tags: java, size, location, desktop

I use `Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(...))` to open a browser in Java. The browser's location and size is determined by the last time it was opened and closed.

Is there a way to tell the browser to open at, for instance :x=100, y=200, w=300, h=500, so it always opens according to my preference ?

Answer (score 0):

I found an example that show how can you use a JEditorPane "to make" a simple browser. Maybe can help. Take a look at:

http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JEditorPane.html

Hope help you. Good luck.